# The source folder does not belong to a GWT Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt

I am using Eclipse Neon and installed GWT Eclipse plugin from marketplace.
I clicked New-> New GWT web application and selected 'Generate a maven project' and 'Generate project sample code' checkboxes

[image]

The folder structure is like

[image]

I am trying to create a new class in client folder. But its showing an error like 'The source folder does not belong to a GWT Project.' I am not able to browse to the required folder.Its showing only src/main/java. I am very new in GWT

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.asayama.docs.gwt.angular.examples</groupId>
<artifactId>Gwt_angular_examples</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>com.asayama.docs.gwt.angular.examples.Gwt_angular_examples</name>

<properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.7.0</gwtVersion>
    <!-- Note: GWT needs at least java 1.6 -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- ensure all GWT deps use the same version (unless overridden) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-codeserver</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.asayama.gwt.angular</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-angular-ng</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-codeserver</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

  <build>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-source</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/com/asayama/docs/gwt/angular/site/examples/public/src/</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>src</directory>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Is `src/main/java` on project's build path?

Comment: yes its in buildpath

Comment: Does your `.gwt.rpc` file contains a line such as `<source path="client" />` ?

Comment: Not .gwt.rpc, but .gwt.xml file contains an entry like <source path="client" />

Comment: My bad, yes, I meant to say `.gwt.xml`. Project properties / Google / Web toolkit : Is there anything in the section "Entry point modules"?

Comment: There is nothing in Google. Is there any difference for 'google plugin for eclipse' and 'gwt plugin for eclipse'. I have installed the 2nd one

Answer (score 0):

Go to properties -> GWT -> General Settings
-->Check Use GWT

[image: Figure 1]